# smoothing nodes values on a graph given adjacency matrix

Tags: smoothing, graph-theory, exponential-smoothing

I am currently looking for a method to smooth values on a graph (composed of vertices and edges).
For example I have a graph with a set of nodes V and I want to be able to smooth it. I could have values on the edges, the problem would be the same using dual graph I guess. 
I am looking for equations I could use, given a smoothing parameter. I have tried to derived mathematically something analogous to exponential smoothing but I failed and I wonder if there is truly a close form solution.
If there is not does anyone have an idea on how to do that with random walk or diffusion processes ? I fear this would work well on a clique but not on a tree that has long and skinny leaves because it would have trouble updating the bottom of the graph.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't understand what you  mean by "smooth values on a graph". Which values do you want to smooth? Usually smoothing refers to a distribution, what is distributed here?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear :
What I want to do is something analogous to exponential smoothing on a graph. So for example let's say i have a graph G(V,E) with values for each vertices in V. I want each values to be not that far from each of his neighbour (given a parameter). 
You could see exponential smoothing on a time series as the same problem but with each node having only two neighbours (time t has neighbours t-1 and t+1). Is that clearer ?

Comment: So it's not the *graph itself* you want to smooth, but the *values at the nodes*, and you want to smooth with the distance between observations based on adjacency in the graph?

Comment: yes ! exactly !

Comment: Your title's kind of misleading then, and the second sentence compounds the confusion it introduces.

Comment: edited to be clearer